# Can we add click on material Ui Box

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Implemented bos and displaying data in loop and showing boxes, On some condition i need to apply disable and enable as like button on box, on enable i have to make click function,Below is my  code what i am trying.

```
<Box className={classes.bookingTicketContainer}>
                      <Box className={classes.bookingBar}>
                        <Box className={classes.bookingSubBox}>
                          <Box className={classes.barInfoboxN1}>
                            <Typography className={classes.durationDetails}> {ticket.ticketsOverview[1]}</Typography>
                          </Box>
                          <Box className={classes.barInfoBoxN2}>
                            <Typography className={classes.changesDetails}>N/A</Typography>
                          </Box>
                          <Box className={classes.barInfoboxN3}>
                            <Typography className={classes.transportModeDetails}>
                              {ticket.ticketsOverview[2]}
                            </Typography>
                          </Box>

                          <Box className={classes.barInfoboxN4}>
                            <Typography className={classes.priceDetails}>N/A</Typography>
                          </Box>

                          {/* <ButtonStyled className={classes.buttonDetails} variant="outlined" value="DETAILS" /> */}
                        </Box>
                      </Box>
                      <button disabled={ticket.ticketsOverview.length < 7} onClick={(e) => handleOnSelectTicket(i)}>
                        {ticket.ticketsOverview.length < 7 ? "NOT AVAILABLE" : "Select"}
                      </button>
                    </Box>
```

for the above code i am getting output as below but i need to remove that buttons and apply click on condition on box.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

***Remove your button tag  & Try this***

```
   {
    ticket.ticketsOverview.length < 7?
     <button disabled onClick={(e) => 
     handleOnSelectTicket(i)}>
       NOT AVAILABLE
     </button>
    :
     <button onClick={(e) => 
     handleOnSelectTicket(i)}>
       Select
     </button>
   }
```